# How to measure group differences incorporating reaction time / accuracy trade-off?

Tags: measurement, methodology, experimental-psychology, reaction-time

In a psychological experiment I am measuring subjects' reaction time as well as their error rate. Now I would like to compare two groups (males & females). There might be a bias in the sense that subjects who respond within a small reaction time might also commit more errors.

- What would be an appropriate way to combine reaction time and error rate to create a measure that takes into consideration this trade-off between "reacting fast" and "reacting correctly".
- E.g., could I just divide reaction time by error rate? Should I center or scale reaction time and error rate before I do this?

Answer (score 11):

The basic approach that you are describing sounds like inverse efficiency scores (e.g., see Townsend and Ashby, 1978,1983), which are measured as

$$\frac{r}{1-e} = \frac{r}{c}$$
where  $r$ is reaction time, $e$ is proportion error, and $c$ is proportion correct. John Christie provides a [critique of inverse efficiency scores here](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/a/668/52) or see the discussion in Bruyer and Brysbaert (2011).

This existing question on ["How to analyze reaction times and accuracy together?"](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/660/how-to-analyze-reaction-times-and-accuracy-together) hopefully answers your question. The answers there generally advocate more sophisticated approaches for combining reaction time and accuracy such as the Linear Ballistic Accumulator Model and Ratcliff's diffusion model.

#### References

- Bruyer, R. & Brysbaert, M. (2011). Combining Speed and Accuracy in Cognitive Psychology: Is the Inverse Efficiency Score (IES) a Better Dependent Variable than the Mean Reaction Time (RT) and the Percentage Of Errors (PE)?. Psychologica Belgica, 51, 5-13. [PDF](http://crr.ugent.be/papers/Bruyer%20&%20Brysbaert%202011.pdf)
- Townsend, J.T., & Ashby,  F.G. (1978). Methods of modeling capacity in simple
  processing systems. In J. Castellan & F. Restle (Eds.), Cognitive theory. Vol. 3.
  (pp. 200-239). Hillsdale, N.J.: Erlbaum.
- Townsend, J.T., & Ashby, F.G. (1983). Stochastic modeling of elementary psychological processes. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press.

Comment: Thanks for the very helpful references! Is there any implemention of the linear ballistic accumulator model or the ratcliff's diffusion model in R?